# Adobe Content Server - set filename for .acsm file

Tags: adobe, drm

I'm using Adobe Content Server (ACS) on our site. I would like to know is it possible in the process of generating GBlink to set filename of the .acsm file?

Right now every .acsm file that users downloaded has name "URLLink.acsm". I found only one mention of this [problem on the forum](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/853687) but no solution is suggested. I'll appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually possible and requires to you modify the web.xml file in the fulfillment.war package. If you open the .war package in a program such as 7-Zip, browse to WEB-INF where you can find web.xml. On or around line 110, you'll find this bit of code:

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>URLLink</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>URLLink.acsm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

You'll want to change it to this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>URLLink</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.acsm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Then in your bookstore you can code URLLink.acsm in the GBLink to be anything you want such as: 'BlahBlahBlah.acsm'.

Comment: Corey, in what parameter of the GBLink I can set filename for .acsm file?

Comment: Hi Tanya,

You would modify the URLLink.acsm right after the /fulfillment/ in the GBLink. So http://your.company.com:8080/fulfillment/URLLink.acsm. You can change the URLLink to anything that you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the only way you can do this is by essentially reverse-proxying the fetching of the ACSM file on behalf of the user - i.e. if you call out to the GBlink yourself, grab the file returned, and then push it on in response to the user's request.

In doing so you will need to set the Content-Type appropriately (application/vnd.adobe.adept+xml), and then you can finally do what you want to do by setting the Content-Disposition header explicitly, to arbitrarily name the file, for example:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=mycustomname.acsm
```

I've ended up doing this in some edge case code, not because I was particularly concerned about arbitrarily naming the file, but because certain mobile browsers, when requesting the GBlink to get the ACSM file directly, would insist on displaying the ACSM XML content directly in the browser. Setting a Content-Disposition: attachment to force download was the only way to solve that, and since Adobe Content Server itself is so inflexible, reverse-proxying the GBlink fetch was really the only way to arbitrarily change the headers on the ACSM response.